# Jackson JsonNode conversion - float precision problems

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I need to convert an object to JsonNode because I need to manipulate the generated Json before returning it.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Float f = 1.4f;
JsonNode node = mapper.convertValue(f, JsonNode.class)
```

Problem is, that `node` contains 1.399999976158142 instead of 1.4. Even if I serialize `node` to JSON...

```
String output = mapper.writeValueAsString(node);
```

.. `output` is 1.399999976158142

If I'm only using writeValueAsString, the result is correct.

Comment: I wouldn't use `float` if using `double` is an option. You always need to apply a sensible rounding when writing floating point values.

Comment: I had the exact same problem, was able to change to a Double relatively easily, but it still seems like a bug?